# What SKLearn classifiers come with class_weight parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, imbalanced-data

Working on an imbalanced project I was wondering what classifiers come with a class_weigth parameter out of the box.

Having been inspired by:

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators

estimators = all_estimators()

for name, class_ in estimators:
     if hasattr(class_, 'predict_proba'):
     print(name)
```

'compute_class_weight' is a function and not a class. So essentially I am looking for a snippet that prints  any classifier that calls for compute_class_weight (to be 'balanced':-) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the classifiers (not all estimators) and check for `class_weight` attribute in the instantiated objects:

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators

estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
for name, class_ in estimators:
    if hasattr(class_(), 'class_weight'): # Note the parenthesis: class_() 
        print(name)
```

Generates the list of the classifiers that can handle class imbalance:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier
ExtraTreeClassifier
ExtraTreesClassifier
LinearSVC
LogisticRegression
LogisticRegressionCV
NuSVC
PassiveAggressiveClassifier
Perceptron
RandomForestClassifier
RidgeClassifier
RidgeClassifierCV
SGDClassifier
SVC
```

---

Note that `class_weight` is an attribute of the *instantiated models* and **not** of the *classes of the models*. The class `LogisticRegression` doesn't have `class_weight`, but a model of type `LogisticRegression`  does. This is the basic Object-Oriented distiction between an instance and a class. 
You can check the difference practically with this code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg_class = LogisticRegression
print(type(logreg_class))
# >>> <class 'type'>

logreg_model = LogisticRegression()
print(type(logreg_model))
# >>> <class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'>
```

During the loop, `class_` refers to the model class and `class_()` is a call to the constructor of that class, which returns an instance.

Comment: I did a mayor fix to my answer since it seems that regressors may have the attribute `class_weight` (although not-accesible) because of the inheritance structure of sklearn (`DecisionTreeRegressor` has `class_weight` attribute, for example, but it's not exposed in the constructor and makes no sense). Now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, the parenthesis caught me out. What do they do?

Comment: `class_` is a reference to the estimator class on each iteration. For example, `DecisionTreeClassifier`, `LogisticRegression`, etc. So doing `class_()` you are actually creating an object of that class: `class_()` translates to, for example, `LogisticRegression()`. You are creating an instance of a class. Assigning the result to a variable may help understanding it: `1. model = LogisticRegression(), 2. hasattr(model, 'class_weight')`. The classes themselves don't have 'class_weight', but the instances do. I'll add some more data to the answer itself now.