# Is MLPClassifier Appropriate for Binary Classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've written a program that uses MLPClassifier to solve a binary classification problem. It sort of works but I am not convinced this is the right model to use.

I have 1300 hextuples of integers to put into one of two classes: class 0 and class 1. A potential issue is that in my training data, 98% are in class 0 so I would get a 98% accuracy from a "prediction function" that always returned "class 0" irrespective of the input.

Is there a machine-learning model that is designed for this type of problem?

==============================================================

TLDR?

My data looks like:

```
X = array([[ 0, 11, 51, 13,  0,  9],
       [51, 13,  0,  9,  0, 11],
       [ 0,  8,  0, 10,  0, 13],
       ...,
       [ 0, 11, 61, 12,  0,  8],
       [ 0,  8,  0,  0, 60, 11],
       [30, 11,  0,  6,  0,  9]])
```

The target is y, a list of 1300 0s and 1s. I used MLPClassifier and got a prediction accuracy of 98%. This was when it occurred to me that by coincidence 98% of the tuples are in class 0, so I would get an accuracy of 98% if I didn't bother with any machine learning and instead guessed the class was always 0.

I checked the fit to see how it fared on just the class 1 tuples, and found that 82% of them are correctly predicted so the accuracy is 82% of 98% i.e. around 80% which I would like to improve, but how?

I have no idea how to change the parameters to MLPClassifier other than blindly increase the size/number of layers, but it occurs to me that I may well be using entirely the wrong sort of model for a learning problem with a Yes/No classification. Also, the integers in the hextuples are not arbitrary and it occurred to me that this may also be relevant to the choice of model. In particular, three of six inputs are always in the range 0 - 15, and the other three are 2-digit codes with three possibilites for the first digit and two for the second.

Any thoughts gratefully recieved.

Code:

```
m = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (256, 128, 64), max_iter=10000) # Pasted from example I found somewhere on the net :(
_ = m.fit(X, y)
yhat = m.predict(X)
cm = confusion_matrix(y, yhat)
print( 'Accuracy = ', np.mean( y == yhat ) )
print( cm )
```

Output:

```
Accuracy =  0.9816653934300993
[[1267   13]
 [  11   18]]

(pdb) class1 = [ i for i in range(len(y)) if y[i] == 1]
(pdb) z = m.predict(np.row_stack((X[q] for q in class1)))
(pdb) z
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
(pdb) len(z), sum(z)
29, 24
```

Comment: `I would get a 98% accuracy from a "prediction function" that always returned "class 0"` MLPRegressor doesn't maximize accuracy - it minimizes log-loss. You want this, especially in imbalanced problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369866/how-can-i-determine-loss-function-for-mlpclassifier-in-skilearn

Comment: You should state your main issue which is that **your dataset has a severe class imbalance**: 49:1 between class 0: class 1. This is an issue for MLP: unlike other classifiers, MLP can't accept different weights per-class/per-sample. So your workaround is either a) stratified undersample the majority class (to get down to 1:1 ratio), b) oversample (or generate synthetic data) on the minority class. This has been answered before: [DataScience.SE: Imbalanced dataset in MLP classifier in python](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19801/imbalanced-dataset-in-mlp-classifier-in-python)

Comment: Search also on SO: [Classification with imbalanced dataset using Multi Layer Perceptrons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759662/classification-with-imbalanced-dataset-using-multi-layer-perceptrons), [What SKLearn classifiers come with class_weight parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395542/what-sklearn-classifiers-come-with-class-weight-parameter), etc...

Comment: I didn't know what my main issue was :-) Thanks for the concept of 'class imbalance' I will go find out about it.

Comment: Best practices when use deep learning model is to normalize your input data. You can achieve it with StandardScaler from scikit-learn.What are the results of using svm or xgboost on the dataset?

Comment: Sorry to be slow to respond. I haven't heard of either package but I will certainly look into it. Normalisation is something I should have thought of - I used to study neural nets in the early '90s but that was a very long time ago and the field is unreconisable (tm) now. Thanks for the ideas!